# Volume buttons on Asus Windows laptop produce unexpected actions

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys, asus-laptop

I have Asus laptop with Windows 10 installed. On the left side of it these are volume buttons, but after some time they suddenly started to work differently. Now

- Hitting one of them makes a screenshot.
- Another one behaves the same as hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

How do I restore default behavior? Googling and searching in Windows settings did not help. I don't even know how these buttons are called properly, since I'm not an English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Asus

- a screenshot is produced using <kbd>Power Button</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is produced by <kbd>Power Button</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>.

According to existing solutions<sup>[link](https://forums.windowscentral.com/microsoft-surface-pro-4/391632-volume-up-rocker-triggers-ctrl-alt-del-help.html)</sup>, make sure no special key utilities are running (to rule them out) and then just check device's power button if it is not stuck (maybe exercise it multiple times to get it unstuck). Or get the button replaced.

Comment: It was exactly because power button was stuck ) Thank you very much!